# Create only one SharePoint App for All version of SharePoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I am creating app for sharePoint. My requirement is, if anyone(with any SharePoint 2013 version) should be able to add my app. without considering available services.
Lets take an example,

My app needed some services like

1. Access Services
2. Visio service
3. User profile synchronization service

In ideal case I will create app by considering SharePoint Enterprise and add above mention services in prerequisites of app.

But if any one who has standard version of SharePoint can only User profile synchronization because it is available in SharePoint Standerd and other 2 (i.e Access service and Visio Services) 
are available in Enterprise only so the person should be able to install the app and can use features accordingly.
(i.e. person should be able to perform operation related to user profile but not for Visio and access services).

In short I have to create only one solution for all versions of sharepoint.

Is there any solution for this situation ?